# Do I need to install all header files and libraries myself when using clang?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, clang

I am a newbie of `clang`. using "`dfn install clang`" command to install `clang`:

```
[root@Fedora include]# dnf install clang
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:16:10 ago on Wed Jun 10 22:32:08 2015.
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================
 Package                         Arch                   Version                       Repository              Size
===================================================================================================================
Installing:
 clang                           x86_64                 3.5.0-9.fc22                  fedora                  13 M
 clang-libs                      x86_64                 3.5.0-9.fc22                  fedora                 4.3 M
 libstdc++-devel                 x86_64                 5.1.1-1.fc22                  fedora                 1.6 M
 llvm                            x86_64                 3.5.0-9.fc22                  fedora                 1.4 M
 llvm-libs                       x86_64                 3.5.0-9.fc22                  fedora                 8.1 M

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================
Install  5 Packages
```

After installation, I find there are only `c++` directory in `/usr/include`.

Installing `gcc` will install all the `glibc`, `kernel`  header files:

```
[root@Fedora shark]# dnf install gcc
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:36:32 ago on Wed Jun 10 22:32:08 2015.
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================
 Package                       Arch                  Version                          Repository              Size
===================================================================================================================
Installing:
 binutils                      x86_64                2.25-5.fc22                      fedora                 5.3 M
 cpp                           x86_64                5.1.1-1.fc22                     fedora                 8.3 M
 gcc                           x86_64                5.1.1-1.fc22                     fedora                  19 M
 glibc-devel                   x86_64                2.21-5.fc22                      fedora                 902 k
 glibc-headers                 x86_64                2.21-5.fc22                      fedora                 493 k
 isl                           x86_64                0.14-3.fc22                      fedora                 490 k
 kernel-headers                x86_64                4.0.4-303.fc22                   updates                994 k
 libmpc                        x86_64                1.0.2-3.fc22                     fedora                  55 k
 mpfr                          x86_64                3.1.2-8.fc22                     fedora                 209 k

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================
Install  9 Packages
```

So, if I want to use `clang`, I need to install all the header files and library personally?

Answer (score -1):

Yes,Because while doing code every header file is required and in case of anyone miss. you will not be able to execute the program.